# Windows phone Configuration

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have 4GB Ram and Windows 8.1 OS and Intel Pentium Dual Core Processor.

Answer (score 1):

There are many requirements to run Windows phone emulator. Two of them are cutting off a relevant part of machines:

- Hyper-V virtualization
- SLAT technology

Here the official documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff626524(v=vs.105).aspx

You do not satisfy these requirements, you can't install it. However you should get a popup reporting that the SDK will be installed without the emulator.